# Evaluation expression popup issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I have this issue when I try to use Evalaute Expressions in debug mode on Mac. The autocomplete popup options appears at back of Evaluate expression window.

If I click on it, the popup brings to front. But it is temporarily.

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2

Any idea?

Thanks

[image: e]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reproducing the same issue since yesterday. It looks like the issue recorded [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205968). It seems to only occur when the Android Studio window is maximized [via the green button in the top left of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aur0k.jpg). A temporary work-around is to un-maximize the window.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!